# Clickable checkbox in Qooxdoo table

Tags: qooxdoo

I'm trying to adapt the Qooxdoo Playground table example's checkbox, to become a checkbox that can be clicked on and off.

I did see some code in a mailing list which seemed like it should do the job, but it's not working for me.

```js
// Display a checkbox in column 3
tcm.setDataCellRenderer(3, new qx.ui.table.cellrenderer.Boolean());

table.addListener("cellClick",
  function(cellEvent) {
    var col = cellEvent.getColumn();
    if (col == 3) {
        oldValue = table.getTableModel().getValue(col, row);
        table.getTableModel().setValue(col, cellEvent.getRow(), !value);
    }
  }
);
```

I've put that into the Playground at https://preview.tinyurl.com/y8qubmll

My intention is to have a few different checkboxes in the columns, so the code above uses the variable "col" rather than hardcoded values.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event is called `cellTap`. See the fixed example below.

```js
table.addListener("cellTap",
    function(cellEvent) {
        var col = cellEvent.getColumn();
        var row = cellEvent.getRow();
        if (col == 3) {
            oldValue = tableModel.getValue(col,row);
            tableModel.setValue(col,row, !oldValue);
        }
    }
);
```

here is a link to the [working example](http://www.qooxdoo.org/5.0.2/playground/#%7B%22code%22%3A%22function%2520createRandomRows(rowCount)%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520var%2520rowData%2520%253D%2520%255B%255D%253B%250A%2520%2520var%2520now%2520%253D%2520new%2520Date().getTime()%253B%250A%2520%2520var%2520dateRange%2520%253D%2520400%2520*%252024%2520*%252060%2520*%252060%2520*%25201000%253B%2520%252F%252F%2520400%2520days%250A%2520%2520var%2520nextId%2520%253D%25200%253B%250A%2520%2520for%2520(var%2520row%2520%253D%25200%253B%2520row%2520%253C%2520rowCount%253B%2520row%252B%252B)%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520date%2520%253D%2520new%2520Date(now%2520%252B%2520Math.random()%2520*%2520dateRange%2520-%2520dateRange%2520%252F%25202)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520rowData.push(%255B%2520nextId%252B%252B%252C%2520Math.random()%2520*%252010000%252C%2520date%252C%2520(Math.random()%2520%253E%25200.5)%2520%255D)%253B%250A%2520%2520%257D%250A%2520%2520return%2520rowData%253B%250A%257D%250A%250A%250A%252F%252F%2520window%250Avar%2520win%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.window.Window(%2522Table%2522).set(%257B%250A%2520%2520layout%2520%253A%2520new%2520qx.ui.layout.Grow()%252C%250A%2520%2520allowClose%253A%2520false%252C%250A%2520%2520allowMinimize%253A%2520false%252C%250A%2520%2520contentPadding%253A%25200%250A%257D)%253B%250Athis.getRoot().add(win)%253B%250Awin.moveTo(30%252C%252040)%253B%250Awin.open()%253B%250A%250A%252F%252F%2520table%2520model%250Avar%2520tableModel%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.table.model.Simple()%253B%250AtableModel.setColumns(%255B%2520%2522ID%2522%252C%2520%2522A%2520number%2522%252C%2520%2522A%2520date%2522%252C%2520%2522Boolean%2522%2520%255D)%253B%250AtableModel.setData(createRandomRows(1000))%253B%250A%250A%252F%252F%2520make%2520second%2520column%2520editable%250AtableModel.setColumnEditable(1%252C%2520true)%253B%250A%250A%252F%252F%2520table%250Avar%2520table%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.table.Table(tableModel).set(%257B%250A%2520%2520decorator%253A%2520null%250A%257D)%253B%250Awin.add(table)%253B%250A%250Avar%2520tcm%2520%253D%2520table.getTableColumnModel()%253B%250A%250A%252F%252F%2520Display%2520a%2520checkbox%2520in%2520column%25203%250Atcm.setDataCellRenderer(3%252C%2520new%2520qx.ui.table.cellrenderer.Boolean())%253B%250A%250A%252F%252F%2520use%2520a%2520different%2520header%2520renderer%250Atcm.setHeaderCellRenderer(2%252C%2520new%2520qx.ui.table.headerrenderer.Icon(%2522icon%252F16%252Fapps%252Foffice-calendar.png%2522%252C%2520%2522A%2520date%2522))%253B%250A%250Atable.addListener(%2522cellTap%2522%252C%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520function(cellEvent)%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520col%2520%253D%2520cellEvent.getColumn()%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520row%2520%253D%2520cellEvent.getRow()%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520alert(col)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520if%2520(col%2520%253D%253D%25203)%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520oldValue%2520%253D%2520tableModel.getValue(col%252Crow)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520tableModel.setValue(col%252Crow%252C%2520!oldValue)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D)%253B%250A%22%2C%20%22mode%22%3A%22ria%22%7D)

Comment: Thanks Tobi. Works perfectly!